# useEffect rewrites the entire store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, redux-thunk

I have a redux store with 3 reducers:

```
let reducers = combineReducers({
config: configReducer,
data: dataReducer,
currentState: gameStateRecuder})

let store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware));
```

In each of those reducers the initial store is empty, but once the App component mounts I use `useEffect` to replace each initial store inside a reducer with the one I receive with `axios.get` using `redux-thunk`. It looks like this in every reducer:

```
let initialState = [];

const SET_STATE = 'SET_STATE';

const configReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_STATE: {
            return { ...action.state};
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }

const setState = (state) => ({ type: SET_STATE, state });

export const getConfigState = () => (dispatch) => {
    getAPI.getConfig() //I import getAPI with all the REST API logic//
    .then(response => {
        dispatch(setState(response));
    })
};
```

And the App trigger is:

```
const App = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    props.getConfigState();
    props.getDataState();
    props.getGameState();
  }, []);
  return (
   //JSX//
  );
}

export default compose(connect(null, { getConfigState, getDataState, getGameState }))(App);
```

However, when the App mounts, I have this mess: [image: console logs for every action]

In the end, I get the state of each reducer replaced with the state of the one whose promise resolved the last one. I can try to wrap the app 2 more times with a HOC that does nothing but re-writes a state of the precise reducer, but I would still like to understand what causes a promise to affect other reducers besides the one he needs to effect.

Comment: You have getDataState and getGameState missing in your question by my guess is they all fire and action of type `SET_STATE`. All reducers are called for all actions so you have to define a relevant set state type, for example: `SET_GAME_STATE `

Comment: @HMR Didn't see your answer and resolved the problem by myself, but thank you, that is exactly what it was. 'All reducers are called for all actions so you have to define a relevant set state type' - to be honest, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 2):

A silly mistake, but maybe someone has the exact same problem - the solution is to give different case names for each reducer - `SET_STATE` need to become `SET_GAME_STATE`, `SET_CONFIG_STATE`, `SET_DATA_STATE` respectivly. I believe that's because of my misunderstanding on how the `dispatch` works.